# Lock or Freeze VBA Code to Prevent Editing

Tags: vba, excel, ide, excel-2010

Is there any way I can lock or freeze the **`VBE`** editor to prevent others from accidentally editing the VBA code?

I don't want to lock down the whole workbook where people can run macros but can't see the code.

I want to let others see the code but don't want them accidentally deleting something and break the program (something even I am prone to doing to my code).

Comment: Set password  project properties

Comment: Why voting to close this thread?

Comment: who is voting to close

Comment: As @Wen21 - locking it will stop them changing it (save as xlsb; is easy to crack the password on xlsm - check other posts on this site).  If you want people to see your code copy it to a Word or Notepad++ document.  Nothing like ideal and requires updating in two places, but does what you asked. :)

Comment: I do this exact thing by setting the referenced addin as read-only. When it is opened, you can see the code, but upon trying to "save" changes you'll get a message asking you to save it somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to Visual Basic, right click your module, select VBA Project Properties..., under protection tab, you can lock your VBA code with password.

Hope this help. ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you want the code to be visible and executable, then you can't stop people from making changes to it.
You can however, stop them from *saving those changes*, by opening the workbook as *read-only*.
You can mark a workbook as read-only in the File Properties from within File Explorer. Or, if your workbook is opened via Automation, then you can specify read-only in the open method.